# Simple NIB Question

Tags: objective-c, ios, nib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you swap the NIB file for a UIViewController that's already on-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016944/can-you-swap-the-nib-file-for-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-on-screen)

How would I go about loading a new NIB file without making the old object nil and re-allocating it?

To clarify, what I need to do is change the currently loaded nib file.

Earlier:

```
viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nib" bundel:nil];
```

Wanted:

```
[viewController1 someMethodToChangeLoadedNib:@"NewNib"];
```

Or some way to circumvent typing `[viewController1.view removeFromSuperview]` then `viewController1 = nil` and reallocating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016944/can-you-swap-the-nib-file-for-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-on-screen  This SO Post looks similar.